# Fecha por rango

Tags: mysql, sql, date

como puedo hacer una consulta de fechas por rango si la fecha es
2017-09-04 - 2017-10-03 -----> asi me la arroja el daterangepicker.
y como no las tengo separadas no puedo hacer un  BETWEEN.

Comment: Deberias explicar mas el contexto? de donde salen las fechas? porque no se puede aplicar between?

Comment: el daterangepicker  me selecciona las fechas por rango. Y al imprimir esa variable me arrajo por ejemplo. 2017-09-04 - 2017-10-03. Es decir el rango de una sola vez. no es como tener dos imput separados y capturar cada vez por separado. este me arroja un rango de una.

Comment: Y porque no las tienes separadas? En mysql puedes usar datepart

Comment: http://www.daterangepicker.com/   estoy usando esto. pero como dije me trae el rango junto, me gustaría separarlos.

Comment: SELECT * FROM compra WHERE fecha_factura BETWEEN '2017/02/22 -2017/02/23' AND '2017/02/22 -2017/02/23' lo hice asi, pero solo me seleccion la primera fecha la otra no =(

Comment: Usas PHP para recoger la fecha?

Comment: ya solucione, supare la variable en dos

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php -----> asi ahora si puedo hacer la consulta..

Comment: $fecha  = $_POST["fecha"];
$fecha_nueva = explode(" ", $fecha);
$fecha1=$fecha_nueva[0]; 
$fecha2=$fecha_nueva[2];  aqui el resultado

Answer (score 0):

La única forma que veo de hacer esto es separando las dos fechas, y la única "marca" por llamarlo así que tengo para separarlas es " - " teniendo en cuenta los espacios ya que las fechas también tienen guiones.

Primero haciendo pruebas determine la forma de poder separar las fechas

```
select substring('2017-09-04 - 2017-10-03',1,instr('2017-09-04 - 2017-10-
03',' - '));

select ltrim(substring('2017-09-04 - 2017-10-03',instr('2017-09-04 - 
2017-10-03','- ')+1));
```

**Tener en cuenta en el segundo select el '- '**

Luego lo único que queda es agregar esto en un select. Yo por una cuestión practica y de legibilidad almacenaría cada una de las fechas en variables y luego las usaría en un select

```
set @fecha1 = (select substring('2017-09-04 - 2017-10-
03',1,instr('2017-09-04 - 2017-10-03',' - ')));
set @fecha2 = (select ltrim(substring('2017-09-04 - 2017-10-
03',instr('2017-09-04 - 2017-10-03','- ')+1)));

select * from tabla where campoFecha between @fecha1 and @fecha2
```

Answer (score 0):

En las etiquetas de tu pregunta no está incluido `php` por lo que los usuarios han podido pensar que deseabas solucionarlo solamente con `MySQL`. Pero viendo que en tus comentarios sitúas que lo has solucionado con código `php`, entonces se sobreentiende que `php` es el lenguaje de servidor que estás usando. Lo mejor en este caso es tomar la cadena que te llega desde el `dateRangePicker` y manipularla para obtener la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin y de esta manera poder hacer la consulta `sql`. Veo por tus comentarios que lo solucionaste utilizando `explode`. Esa sería una solución, pero tienes algunas más:

> Estas soluciones son válidas si te aseguras que el `dateRangePicker` siempre entregará las fechas en ese formato, debes probar muy bien tu código en diferentes entornos.

**1 - Utilizando [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) (la solución que utilizaste)**

```
$fecha  = $_POST['fecha'];
$array  = explode(' - ', $fecha);
$fecha1 = $array[0];
$fecha2 = $array[1];
```

[Ejemplo en Ideone](https://ideone.com/oXUC8d)

**2 - Utilizando [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) y una expresión regular que hace match de las dos fechas capturando cada una en un grupo**

```
$fecha  = $_POST['fecha'];
$reg    = '/^([^\s]+)[^\d]+([^\s]+)$/';
$fecha1 = preg_replace($reg, '$1', $fecha);
$fecha2 = preg_replace($reg, '$2', $fecha);
```

[Ejemplo en Ideone](https://ideone.com/ksg2Ay)

**3 - Utilizando [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) y una expresión regular que hace match de cualquier cadena que no contenga espacios**

```
$fecha  = $_POST['fecha'];
$fechas = preg_match_all('/[^\s]+/', $fecha, $matches);
$fecha1 = $matches[0][0];
$fecha2 = $matches[0][2];
```

[Ejemplo en Ideone](https://ideone.com/YT0YP5)

**4 - Utilizando [substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)**

```
$fecha  = $_POST['fecha'];
$fecha1 = substr($fecha, 0, 10);
$fecha2 = substr($fecha, 13, 10);
```

[Ejemplo en Ideone](https://ideone.com/729pCY)